# Electron - user input in title bar

Tags: electron

I am trying to dabble in electron, and i am trying to put a form within the title bar.

I accept I may have to make it a frameless window and then add my own custom html and style.

I am new to the language so this is as far as I have gotten.

what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: how about people suggest whats wrong, toxic community of SO.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a read about [frameless windows](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md). There it will teach you how to make a custom titlebar with HTML and CSS, a small example of which:

**main.js**

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, frame: false });
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
win.show();
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <div style="-webkit-app-region: drag" id="titlebar">
    <input type="text" /> <!-- this is your input in the titlebar -->
  </div>
  <div id="content">your content here</div>
</body>
```

Use `-webkit-app-region: drag` to make your element draggable (note that only rectangular shapes are currently supported).

The rest is up to you to style it however you like!
If you want to make it appear like a native app maybe have a look into [reactdesktop](http://reactdesktop.js.org/).

Comment: im trying to build a very basic web browser (just as a way to practice). why do you suggest react for it to appear native? is this not the point of electron? please educate me, JS has always been the bane of my existence, so any help would be great.